# Getting undefined when trying to read my .env file using dotenv

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

Im having trouble with getting the values from my .env file.

Here's my code:

```
require('dotenv').config()

console.log("Host: " + process.env.HOST);
```

And my .env file is

```
HOST = "localhost"
```

Here's a pic from my directories: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xwIq.png)

I keep getting undefined no matter what. I have tried specifying the path too. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: `dotenv.config()` without any parameters looks for a file named `.env` (and only `.env` ie nothing before the `.`) in the current working directory and throws an exception if it doesn't find one. In your screenshot I can only see a file named `keys.env`. So if your app doesn't throw an exception, you are either using different code or different files or you are silently catching and ignoring the exception, in which case of course your environment won't contain the values from the `keys.env`

Comment: Furthermore you *may* also have an issue with your current working directory because we don't know from where you are starting your `server/index.js`, ie what the current working directory is. Might be the root of the outer package, might be the root of the `server` package, nobody knows ...

Answer (score 7):

You can solve this error in two ways:

1. Rename your `key.env` to `.env` in your project root directory
2. If you must name your `.env` file, then the `config()` expects the path of your file. So in your code provide the path as follows:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: 'keys.env'})
```

Comment: Good first answer @kalyan-adhikari

Answer (score 1):

Ok so for your case, **remove your env file** and try again like this :

After installing the package with install dotenv --save :

At your terminal and the root directory of your project, run this command to create the new env file: **touch .env**

you should see the file with a **locker**, now since you have trouble to make it work, make sure to place your file, for ex your index.js, **at the same root with .env**  otherwise you have to specify the right path, but let's make it as simple as possible first, than import de package, put it at the top of the file, and i hope i am guessing right that you use CommonJs :

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

now to write the variable on the .env, for example you have this secret string you want to hide it :

Mysecretapikeyandpasswordtogetaccessmysql

than write for example in the .env like this **without space and any quote string ""** :

```
DATABASE_URL=Mysecretapikeyandpasswordtogetaccessmysql
```

now you can replace on your file this secret with the new variable :

```
process.env.DATABASE_URL
```

Try again restart your app and Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

The module works in a way that if you the Default Path is  `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')` so it expects the file to be at the root and named '.env'.

In case it's in a different location or with a different name you should specify a custom path.

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the fact, that `dotenv` confused USER (of the system) with USERNAME (of the mysql database). Actually USER returns the current system user instead of the mysql database user, which I have set to USERNAME in the .env file for convenience. Now it was able to connect to the database!

To check this, you could use:
`console.log(process.env.USER);`
and:
`console.log(process.env.USERNAME);`

1st gives you the system user, whereas the
2nd gives the database user.

Comment: I saw a related post yesterday and it seems like this issue is related to the ability of Linux to use USER as the system user (or the root user), which was different in my case from the database username. This is very likely to be the case, since I am using Linux, as an OS.